# Parameter 0 of constructor in ContentManagerServiceImpl required a bean of type PropertyFacade' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

El error que me salta al ejecutar Spring es este:

> Field contentManagerService in
> com.xxxx.xxxx.negocio.impl.ContentManagerManager required a bean of
> type 'com.xxxx.xxxxx.cm.IContentManagerService' that could not be
> found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.xxxx.yyyy.cm.IContentManagerService' in your configuration.

**ContentManager.java**

```
@Service
public class ContentManagerManager implements IContentManagerManager {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ContentManagerManager.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private IContentManagerService contentManagerService; //¿fail here?

    private final String usuarioCM;
    private final String claveCM;
    private final String tipoDocumentalCM;
    private final String tempFiles;

    @Autowired
    public ContentManagerManager(final PropertyFacade propertyFacade) {
        this.usuarioCM = propertyFacade.property("content.manager.user");
        this.claveCM = propertyFacade.property("content.manager.password");
        this.tipoDocumentalCM = propertyFacade.property("content.manager.tipoDocumental");
        this.tempFiles = propertyFacade.property("tempFiles");
    }
```

**Mi appConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxxx.yyyyy.negocio", "com.xxxxx.yyyyy.dominio",
        "com.xxxx.yyyyy.yyyy.rest", "com.xxxxx.yyyyy.persistencia" })
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public PropertyFacade propertyFacade() throws IOException {
        return new PropertyFacade("classpath:application.properties");
    }
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- Property Configurer -->
<bean id="propertyFacade"
    class="com.konecta.utils.properties.PropertyFacade">
    <constructor-arg
        value="classpath:application.properties"></constructor-arg>
</bean>


<!-- MGA y Content Manager -->
<import resource="appCtxClientesServiciosWeb.xml" />
```

Comment: Pon el código de IContentManagerService y su implementación.

Comment: @PabloFradua es una interfaz externa , no tengo acceso a ella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si esa interfaz externa forma parte de una librería de Spring, y su implementación está anotada con `@Service` o `@Component`, podría valerte con añadir el paquete correspondiente en los paquetes a inspeccionar en el `@ComponentScan` de tu clase `AppConfig`.

En caso contrario, tendrás que crear un método anotado con `@Bean`, tal y como haces con `PropertyFacade`, para que el `@Autowired` de `IContentManagerService` en `ContentManager` sepa cómo inyectar el objeto que necesitas.