# Parameter 0 of constructor en SpringBoot al utilizar "MapStruct"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

Muy buenas! Antes de comenzar, quiero aclarar que he tratado de resolver mi problema leyendo [Parameter 0 of constructor in ContentManagerServiceImpl required a bean of type PropertyFacade' that could not be found](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/454805/parameter-0-of-constructor-in-contentmanagerserviceimpl-required-a-bean-of-type) pero la solución no ha sido válida para mi caso.

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un backend (muy básico por ahora), enfocándolo hacia arquitectura hexagonal y DDD, adjunto captura de la estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema parte cuando trato de utilizar la librería "mapstruct" para mapear mis entidades a DTO's y devolverlo (si no hago uso de esta librería, no aparece el mensaje de error, o eso quiero pensar:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.selling.lolproject.infrastructure.persistence.EuwAccountsPersistenceImpl required a bean of type 'com.selling.lolproject.infrastructure.persistence.EuwAccountsRepository' that could not be found.
> Action:
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.selling.lolproject.infrastructure.persistence.EuwAccountsRepository' in your configuration.

Adjunto código de las clases indicadas en el log:

```
public interface EuwAccountsRepository extends JpaRepository<EuwAccounts, Long> {
}
--------------------------------------------------------
@Repository
public class EuwAccountsPersistenceImpl implements EuwAccountsPersistence {

    private final EuwAccountsRepository euwAccountsRepository;
    @Autowired
    public EuwAccountsPersistenceImpl(EuwAccountsRepository euwAccountsRepository) {
        this.euwAccountsRepository = euwAccountsRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<EuwAccounts> getAllEuwAccounts() {
        return this.euwAccountsRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<EuwAccounts> getEuwAccountById(Long euwAccountId) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public EuwAccounts saveAccount(EuwAccounts euwAccountsId) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEuwAccount(Long euwAccountId) {

    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------
@Service
public class EuwAccountsServiceImpl implements EuwAccountsService {


    private final EuwAccountsPersistence euwAccountsPersistence;

    private final EuwAccountsMapper euwAccountsMapper;

    @Autowired
    public EuwAccountsServiceImpl(EuwAccountsPersistence euwAccountsPersistence, EuwAccountsMapper euwAccountsMapper) {
        this.euwAccountsPersistence = euwAccountsPersistence;
        this.euwAccountsMapper = euwAccountsMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public List<EuwAccountsDTO> getAllEuwAccounts() {
        List<EuwAccounts> listEuwAccounts = euwAccountsPersistence.getAllEuwAccounts();
        return euwAccountsMapper.toDto(listEuwAccounts);
    }
}


------------------------------------------------------

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EuwAccountsMapper extends EntityMapper<EuwAccountsDTO, EuwAccounts>{
    default EuwAccounts fromId(Long id) {

        if (id == null) return null;

        EuwAccounts category = new EuwAccounts();
        category.setId(id);
        return category;
    }

}

------------------------------------------------------
public interface EntityMapper <D, E>{
    E toEntity(D dto);
    D toDto(E entity);
    List<E> toEntity(List<D> dto);
    List<D> toDto(List<E> entity);
}
```

El resto de clases tienen las anotaciones pertinentes, entidades @Entity, controladores @RestController, etc.

Muchas gracias de antemano a cualquier ayuda y respuesta. Un saludo!

Comment: Ya lo he editado, muchas gracias por el aviso. Un saludo! @Israel-ICM